# Issue Creating IR in Azure Data factory with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create an Azure Integration Runtime with VNet config Enabled.
But when I try to run it with Terraform it gives the below error:

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on DataFactory.tf line 44, in resource "azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_azure" "managed_ir":
  44:   virtual_network_enabled = true

An argument named "virtual_network_enabled" is not expected here.
```

My Terraform snippet:

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_azure" "managed_ir" {
  name                = "${local.prefix_kebab}-Managed-IR"
  data_factory_name   = azurerm_data_factory.datafactory.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.RG.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.RG.location
  virtual_network_enabled = true
}
```

I am not sure why it gives the ablove error as it is according to the documentation provided on terraform official website ([terraform doc link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory_integration_runtime_azure)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the latest ***azurerm provider for terraform*** i.e. `v2.88.1`. I tested using the same in my environment with the below code:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "myrg"
}
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                = "ansumantestadf"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  managed_virtual_network_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_azure" "example" {
  name                = "ansumanadf-IR"
  data_factory_name   = azurerm_data_factory.example.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  virtual_network_enabled = true
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]